# Scipy: how to fit only a tail of distribution?

Tags: scipy

I have a list of floats `data`, representing tail, sampled from a Generalized Pareto distribution.

I want to fit that tail and find shape/scale/loc parameters:

```py
from scipy.stats import genpareto


genpareto_shape, genpareto_location, genpareto_scale = genpareto.fit(data)  # shape, location, scale
x = np.linspace(0, 43000, 1000)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))
plt.hist(data, density=True, bins='auto', histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(x, genpareto.pdf(x, genpareto_shape, scale=genpareto_scale, loc=genpareto_location), 'k-', lw=2, label='frozen pdf')

plt.show()
```

[image]

You have probably already guessed, what my problem is: due to the fact that the data represent only a tail of distribution, not the full distribution, maximum likelihood does its best to keep the fitting distribution more or less 0 in the ranges of $x$, where I have no data points, which leads to bad results, where the data points are actually available.

Is there a way to ask scipy to fit the data only within a specific range of $x$ values?